# Spring boot JPA query for table with pair values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table in my database with the following columns: id, value, and valuePair.

Here is the data in my table:

| id | value | valuePair |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa1 | aa2 |
| 2 | aa2 | aa1 |
| 3 | aa3 | aa5 |
| 4 | aa4 | null |
| 5 | aa5 | aa3 |

I need to retrieve only one row using a JPA query, where there is a valid pair present.

For example, these rows would be acceptable:

id:1, value: 'aa1', valuePair: 'aa2'

id:3, value: 'aa3', valuePair: 'aa5'

It doesn't matter which specific pair is returned.

I currently have this solution:

```
@Query("select t1 from Entity t1 left join Entity t2 on t1.value = t2.valuePair and t2.value = t1.valuePair WHERE t1.value < t2.value")
```

However, I'm interested in exploring a more sophisticated approach.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a sophisticated approach in the effort of putting logic into database (queries) - maybe you should look for a more suitable model that reflects your needs better?